# Is there a way to create SQL procedures to act as a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to register in pivot tables automatically, when the two entities are created? I had tried with triggers something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_example AFTER INSERT ON `formations` AND `tags`...
```

But as triggers only work for a table, it didn't work (as you can see). So does anyone know if you can put a solution with procedures or something else?

Comment: no there isn't in mysql you have to add for every table and every type a new trigger, that a fact of life

Comment: Perhaps a view is an alternative?

Comment: View for many to many tables?

Comment: Please describe the task, not your (incorrect) attempt to solve.

Comment: Maybe an event which runs periodically and executes your existing code to regenerate the pivot table(s) perhaps augmented by triggers which capture the fact that a table used in creating the pivot tables has changed and therefore the pivot table(s) need to be regenerated.

Comment: I think this doesn't make much sense... I wanted to know if there's a way to set the fields of the pivot table every time the entities of this relationship are created... Example:
`formations` and `tags`, I have an intermediate table between them as `formation_tag`, so every time the formation and the tag are created in the same request, it sets this table automatically...